# Android checking Wifi on every onRestart

Tags: android, application-restart

I want my app to check whether the device is connecting to a specific Wifi and auto connect to the Wifi whenever the app is navigated to. I know that I can do it in onRestart(). But it only handles one activity's state.

My question is if there any method to handle the state of the app instead of adding onRestart() on every activity to do what i want?

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
   import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;


     public class AutostartService extends BroadcastReceiver {  

     @Override  
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 System.out.println("in broad....");
 ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
   boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

   if(!is3g && !isWifi){

   }else{
 if ((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")))
    {
        System.out.println("in broadcast receiver.....");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Splash.class);  
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        context.startActivity(i);  
    }
   }
        }

       }
```

dont forget to add this in your manifest file:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AutostartService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
      - <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
             </intent-filter>
              </receiver>
```

and the following permissions in manifest file:

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Thanks. RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED is broadcasted after turning on the mobile, right? But I want to do the checking on every start of the application (similar to onRestart() method but applying on every activity).

Comment: yes you are right... do the same in launching of your application everytime